# Initializing objects dynamically

Tags: java, object

The following code is a simplified version. The `Write` and `Read` are classes that implement the `IAction` interface.

```
IAction newAction;
if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("WRITE")){
    newAction = new Write();
}
else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("READ")){
    newAction = new Read();
}
...
```

If I had many actions to implement then i would have to go through too many if statements. So the question is if there is a way to automatically create each class without getting through all these if statements?

Comment: While I am thinking about using reflection, I found here a lot of good solution and some new ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I depends on what you mean by "automatically". Computers do things automatically, but not before someone programmed to do something automatically. You probably mean "less cumbersome". Here is an approach that uses Java 8 features.

```
// Make a Map that tells what word should be coupled to what action
Map<String, Supplier<IAction>> actionMapping = new HashMap<>();
actionMapping.put("WRITE", Write::new);
actionMapping.put("READ", Read::new);

// When you get user input, simply lookup the supplier
// in the map and call get() on it
IAction action = actionMapping.get(userInput.toUpperCase()).get();
```

If you're not using Java 8, you can use a slightly different (but similar) approach:

```
// Map that tells what word should be coupled to what action
Map<String, Class<? extends IAction>> actionMapping = new HashMap<>();
actionMapping.put("WRITE", Write.class);
actionMapping.put("READ", Read.class);

// Lookup the action class for the input and instantiate it
IAction action = actionMapping.get(userInput.toUpperCase()).newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible. First create an Object. Then check if the Classname exists to make sure that the userinput is a valid class, then create a dynamic class. After that assign it to your Object.

```
Object newAction = null;

 try {
  Class<?> clazz =  Class.forName( "your.fqdn.class."+userInput );
  Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
  newAction = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
  newAction = new your.fqdn.class."+userInput;
 } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
   // catch an error if the class for the object does not exists.
}
```

You can later check for the class by using

```
if (newAction instanceOf MyClass) { } 
else if (newAction instanceOf Anotherclass) {}
```

But be carefull. This is for security reasons not recommend. You should validate the input before you do that!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enum.

```
public enum Action implements IAction{
    READ,WRITE;
}
```

And use it in one line like so.

```
IAction action = Action.valueOf(userInput.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a enum and implement the interface for each enum constant. Here's an example for implementing [`Consumer<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

```
public enum Action implements java.util.function.Consumer<String> {
    READ {
        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
            System.out.println("Read: "+t);
        }
    },
    WRITE {
        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
            System.out.println("Write: "+t);
        }
    };
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Consumer<String> c = Action.valueOf("READ");
c.accept("Greetings!");
c = Action.valueOf("WRITE");
c.accept("Hello World!");
```

This will print

```
Read: Greetings!
Write: Hello World!
```

You can use [`String.toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) get the right constant regardless of upper and lower case.